# VS 2015 RTM MVC not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

Here is the summary of what was going on:

I had VS 2015 RC Enterprise installed. When I tried to install VS 2015 Community over it, it was blocked because it had enterprise installed. Tried to uninstall that, said it is not really installed and if I want to just remove it from list of installed products. Uninstalled from command line with /uninstall /force, worked but the community installer still complained. Went few rounds with installing VS 2015 Enterprise RTM, uninstalling that, and then trying to install community edition, but it still thought Enterprise was installed. Finally I fired up procmon and started deleting registry entries from VS 2015 that it was referencing and finally got it to install.

So now I am here - things seem to work except MVC support:

[image: MVC error]

I repaired, modified, uninstalled and installed again a few times, no joy. 
ActivityLog.xml says this:

```
<description>CreateInstance failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Package.MvcPackage]</description>
<guid>{B54016DB-B3E6-4960-8262-81772C777DE9}</guid>
<hr>80070002</hr>
<errorinfo>Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.5.0, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</errorinfo>
```

I've run out of ideas as to what else I can do to make this work, any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you ever have earlier releases than RC installed, before Ultimate was renamed to Enterprise?

If you have VS RTM (Community, Professional, or Enterprise) installed you can try the following:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio
2. Run the following from a command prompt to forcibly remove MVC: **msiexec /x {61A70737-1FE8-E16A-8791-5C8D54990F5B} IGNOREDEPENDENCIES=ALL**
3. Open appwiz.cpl (Add/Remove Programs), click on Visual Studio 2015, select change and then select the Modify option once the installer is launched.

Thanks,
Jacques

Comment: This helped a lot - I don't get the mvcpackage error anymore but I do get the following: "Keyboard History Utility has stopped working" popup. Also, if I create a new mvc web application things seem to work ok, however if I open an existing mvc app, there are a lot of errors in razor views ("The name 'model' does not exist in the current context " The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context", Html.Partial not recognized, ...)

Comment: The ViewBag error and similar ones are probably related to the editor not loading the correct parser. You can check under the Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Web\Razor folder. It should contain the MVC and Razor DLLs the editors rely on to provide intellisense. There should be a v3 and v4 folder